# How to pass System.getProperty("skipIndexing") value to a Java Server while starting?

Tags: java, mule, system-properties

We are using Mule Server but this question is generally for all server.

In constructor we have following property named skipindexing.

```
if (!Boolean.parseBoolean(System.getProperty("skipIndexing"))) {
            //searchIndexer.doIndexing(propertyIndexing, threadsToLoadObjects, threadsForSubsequentFetching);
         }
```

Every time i need to comment this code to run on server because i do not know how to pass this skipIndexing property on runtime.

Could anyone suggest how to pass this value as false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set property in `mule/conf/wrapper.conf`

Comment: Thanks. and if in tomcat then?

Comment: use environment variable, JAVA_OPTS in setenv.bat or sh

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by pass it to server, but setting that system property "skipIndex" could be set on the command line of your app by adding it with the -D flag as

```
java -DskipIndexing=true -jar ....
```

HTH,
Gal

Comment: Like Mule start or stop is done like "mule start" then should it be done like mule start -DskipIndexing=true or tomcat startup.bat -DskipIndexing=false ?

Comment: I am not familiar with mule, if mule is a .bat file than you might want to check that file, it might have the java command in it? if it runs under tomcat's startup.bat than you could add the -D inside the startup.bat